# Javascript help to change color in writeln

Tags: javascript, css

Can you explain me why this line isn't displayed ?

```
document.writeln("<p style=\"color:red;"> error value must be >= 1 </p>");
```

I want the text to be red

Thank you

Comment: Check the syntax highlighting on that string...See that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.writeln("<p style=\"color:red;\"> error value must be >= 1 </p>");
```

You forgot to escape the second quote mark (after the `color: red;`).

Answer (score 1):

The quotes around `"color:red;"` needs to be single quotes, or both has to be escaped.

`'color:red;'`

`\"color:red;\"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.writeln("<p style='color:red;'> error value must be >= 1 </p>");
```